# How to use autocomplete in web page in php?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have created a simple webpage with a simple search engine in php and MySQL separately.

Here is the index.php:

```
<form action="search.php" method="get" >
Please search here:
    <input type="text" name="query" id="text"  />
 <input type="submit" name="submit" id="search" value="Search" />
</form>
```

search.php:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("", "", "") or die("Error connecting to database: ".mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("search-engine") or die(mysql_error());
    $term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));//retrieve the search term that autocomplete sends

$qstring = "SELECT description as value,id FROM test WHERE description LIKE '%".$term."%'";
$result = mysql_query($qstring);//query the database for entries containing the term

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))//loop through the retrieved values
{
        $row['value']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['value']));
        $row['id']=(int)$row['id'];
        $row_set[] = $row;//build an array
}
echo json_encode($row_set);//format the array into json data
    $query = $_GET['query'];
    $min_length = 3;
  if(strlen($query) >= $min_length)
  {
        $query = htmlspecialchars($query);
        $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
  echo "<table border='0' width='300' align='center' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1'>";
  echo "<tr><h3>You have searched for $query...Please find the details of $query...</h3></tr>";
  echo "<tr align='center' bgcolor='#03acfa' > <td height='35px' width='150px'><b>Mobile Name</b></td> <td><b>Mobile Type</b></td></tr>";
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mobiles WHERE (`name` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`type` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
  {
            while($results = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
                echo "<tr align='center' bgcolor='#93dafb'><td height='25px'>".$results['name']."</td> <td>".$results['type']."</td></tr>" ;
            }

        }
        else{
            echo "<tr align='center' bgcolor='#fdee03'><td colspan='2' height='25px'>Sorry..No results for $query</td><tr>";
   echo "</table>";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "Your search keyword contains letters only ".$min_length;
    }
?>
```

Here is the index.html web page:(for instance)

```
<div>
<p>Saina Nehwal poses with the World Junior Badminton Championship trophy at the Shiv Chattrapati Sports Complex in this November 2, 2008.</p>
</div>
```

I used the code from this link http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

So I need to use the above php search engine on the index.

For example, if I search for "Saina", it will have to find it.
I'm not quite sure how I'm supposed to implement the autocomplete feature.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you even tried anything to achive this? And no offense but if you just google for example jquery autocomplete you will find a few with clear documentation how you can integrate it

Comment: I am struggling how to use? @LeventeNagy .thanks

Comment: where are you stuck..? what help do you need

Comment: Here: https://www.google.hu/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=jquery+autocomplete+with+php+example&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=py8dVbrAH4b7Ut__g6gI

Comment: you can create an external php file and use it. return json result from there

Comment: If you get stuck from what i linked, atleast please try, if are really stuck with it, comment and i will help

Comment: actually. i don't need like this output.. i need a search engine like this website http://www.gatesnotes.com ,used, If i type some word, it will be shows that corresponding word in the whole website. thanks @LeventeNagy